# Variable initialization (pointer and value)

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, variable-initialization

```
Foo f1 = Foo();      // (1) Ok
Foo f2 = Foo;        // (2) Compiler error

Foo *p1 = new Foo(); // (3) Ok
Foo *p2 = new Foo;   // (4) Ok. Why??
```

I was wondering why there exists two ways to initialize pointers. It looks a little inconsistent. Is there some logical reason, and if so, what? Or, maybe it's some kind of legacy? And if so, What is the origin of such notation?

Comment: Try `new int` vs `new int()`.

Comment: Try reading them out loud, with *x* `()` pronounced "make an *x*".

Comment: Now I'm curious. The case of `Foo f3;` is also interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit... complicated, to say the least.

When dealing with objects, both notations are equivalent. When dealing with primitive types (such as `int`), `(3)` will initialize (zero fill) the value, while `(4)` will not (the value will be left undefined).

For automatically allocated objects, this:

```
Foo f1;
```

Declares and initializes a `Foo` object using the default constructor. This:

```
Foo f2 = Foo();
```

Declares and initializes a `Foo` object using the copy constructor, essentially copying the value of a temporary object (the `Foo()`), which is built with the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I give you that it seems illogical, but if you think about the possible meanings, it makes a lot of sense.

Without knowing what `Foo` might be, neither a human nor the compiler (here, the human perspective is more important) would be able to determine if `Foo f2 = Foo;` is a) creating a new temporary `Foo` object and copy constructing another one with it or b) assigning the value of a variable `Foo` to the copy constructed object (`f2`). It may seem obvious for us because our convention tells us that `Foo` must be a type as it is capitalised, but in general it is not that simple (again: this mainly applies to a human reader that does not necessarily have the whole source code memorised).

The difference between `(2)` and `(4)` is that for the latter, only one interpretation is admissible, because `new var` (where `var` is a variable) is not a legal expression.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of 4 for scope-based resources is actually just

```
Foo f;
```

The legacy reason for the differences is essentially that in C, primitive types, such as `int`, were not default-initialized to something useful. C++ inherited this behaviour for performance reasons- at the time. Of course, now, it's a trivial amount of processor time to expend. In C++, they introduced a new syntax by which it would always be initialized- the brackets.

```
int i = int();
```

`i` is always guaranteed to be 0.

```
int i;
```

The value of `i` is undefined.

This is the exact same as for the pointer variety, just with some `new`:

```
int* i = new int(); // guaranteed 0
int* i = new int; // undefined
```