# What's the difference between new MyClass and new MyClass()

Tags: c++, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between A* pA = new A; and A* pA = new A();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581763/difference-between-a-pa-new-a-and-a-pa-new-a)
>   [Variable initialization (pointer and value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961015/variable-initialization-pointer-and-value)

Assuming that `MyClass` has a default constructor, what's the difference between

```
MyClass *mc = new MyClass;
```

and

```
MyClass *mc = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Assuming that you mean a user-declared default constructor, in this case there is no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assuming that MyClass has a default constructor

2 extra characters in the code.

If the class is a POD type (not your case), the latter will perform **value-initialization**.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
Is it another trap in C++ ?

Comment: I just come up with another question, if the two sentences are basically the same thing.Why C++ accept this ambiguity ? Is it some kind of compromise to the compatibility？ Can anyone provide any reference ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean two different syntax，have the same meaning.Of course in my case.

Comment: @Alan they have the same meaning in some cases (as stated in the answer).

Comment: :) thanks again. C++ is killing me.